# Limiting the degree of a node in a Graph

Tags: scala, design-patterns, graph, degrees

I am trying to write a small application using [Scala-Graph](http://www.scala-graph.org/). It is a nifty package alright, but while modelling the application's entities, I am facing a question.

Let us say that we are modelling employees in an organisation. An `Employee` belongs to only one `Department` but can belong to two or more `SocialClub`. If we consider the `Organisation` as a Graph, then

```
var organisation = Graph[Employee,GroupsInOffice]()
// .....
val e1 = Employee (1, "Nirmalya")
val d1 = Department("Finance")
val d2 = Department("Sales"
val club1 = Club("Beer Drinkers")
val club2 = Club("Horse Riders")
// ....
```

So, the following should be allowed:

```
organisation = organisation(e1 ~> club1,e1 ~> club2)
```

But, the following should *not* be allowed:

```
organisation = organisation(e1 ~> d1,e1 ~> d2)
```

My question is what is the pattern one adopts to ensure the prevention. Should it be a constraint that is defined on the Graph itself (*organisation*) or should it be a application-level check that counts the the number of times `e1` is used in setting the relationship (`~`)? Is there any other particular approach that one takes in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of (re)search, I have found that the [library](http://www.scala-graph.org/) itself has made provisions for defining User-defined (Application-driven) *Constraints* on the Graph. The package

```
scalax.collection.constrained.constraints
```

provides some of the pre-defined and useful constraints. What is interesting is that it is possible to write our own constraints by following a certain set of steps and providing bodies of callback functions. More information can be had here: http://www.scala-graph.org/guides/constrained.html#Implementing. I am yet to complete my work which uses such a constraint, but hopefully I soon will.